# Xubuntu 22.04 iso size bump versus 20.04

Tags: xubuntu, iso

There is a drastically size bump between iso of Xubuntu 22.04 and 20.04.2.

It is 2.7GB vs 1.7GB.

What is the reason for that drastically increase?

**EDIT:**

Found an info in the cache of a search engine where it says, it is a bug, but not anymore?!

[image]

Bug, yes or no? On distrowatch the [main package difference](https://distrowatch.com/dwres-mobile.php?firstlist=xubuntu&secondlist=xubuntu&firstversions=0&resource=compare-packages&secondversions=4) is the samba package new in 22.04.

Has anyone the correct answer for us to post it? Thanks!

Comment: The [Xubuntu release notes](https://wiki.xubuntu.org/releases/22.04/release-notes) may provide some clues as to why there's an extra gigabyte in the ISO. If you need a minimal install of Xubuntu 22.04, you could try [Xubuntu Core](https://unit193.net/xubuntu/core/), which is 1.24GB in size. Do note that you'll need to install most of your applications manually, as the core release contains just the basics.

Comment: Thx, Xubuntu Core is a nice hint.

Comment: Gimp and Libreoffice are included in both. So could it be due to the snap of Firefox? I really have no clue what takes the extra size.